# SQL Query to get the User account OIU_Key

Tags: identity, identity-management, oim, identitymanager

Is there a SQL query to get get User Accounts which are in provisioned or enabled state for a particular resource?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT usr.usr_login,usr.usr_key,obj.obj_name,obi.obi_key,oiu.oiu_create,
ost.ost_status,oiu.oiu_key,obj.obj_key FROM orc, usr, obj, oiu, ost, obi WHERE 
orc.orc_key = oiu.orc_key AND  oiu.usr_key = usr.usr_key AND oiu.ost_key = ost.ost_key AND oiu.obi_key = obi.obi_key AND obi.obj_key = obj.obj_key AND obj.obj_name='<Resource Object Name>' AND (ost.ost_status='Provisioned' OR ost.ost_status='Enabled') AND usr.usr_login='<Enter Userlogin>';
```